# Error when editing a MediaWiki instance using Emacs with mediawiki.el

Tags: emacs, mediawiki

I got some error when editing a Mediawiki instance using Emacs with mediawiki.el

Versions of softwares:

OS: Mac
Emacs: GNU Emacs 24.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, NS apple-appkit-1038.36)
mediawiki-el: The comment text says "2.2.3" and the function definition says 2.2.4 (inconsistent?)

```
...
;; Version: 2.2.3
;; Created: Sep 17 2004
;; Keywords: mediawiki wikipedia network wiki
;; URL: http://launchpad.net/mediawiki-el
;; Last Modified: <2012-05-27 22:06:10 mah>

(defconst mediawiki-version "2.2.4"
  "Current version of mediawiki.el")
...
```

When I try to connect to a mediawiki site, I get error

```
Posting to: http://en.wikipedia.org/api.php
Contacting host: en.wikipedia.org:80
xml-parse-tag: XML: (Not Well-Formed) Invalid end tag (expecting link) at pos 3712
```

I have in .emacs the following

```
'(mediawiki-site-alist (quote (("Wikipedia" "http://en.wikipedia.org/" "foobar" "" "XXX"))))
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Which page were you trying to edit, which resulted in that parser error?

Comment: "editing" is not specifically referring to the action,  I think the error stops me from even logging into / accessing the entry page, i.e. the "Main" page of the Mediawiki instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's a compatibility issue between [`mediawiki.el` 2.2.4](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/106282214/mediawiki.el) and GNU Emacs 24.*, at least the one installed via Mac Ports under port `emacs-app @24.1_0`.  I suspect this because if I roll back to `emacs-app @23.4.1`, the problem immediately goes away.

To roll back to earlier version of Emacs via Mac Ports:

```
$ sudo port installed emacs-app
The following ports are currently installed:
  emacs-app @23.3_3
  emacs-app @23.3_4
  emacs-app @23.4_0
  emacs-app @23.4_1
  emacs-app @24.1_0
  emacs-app @24.2_0+fullscreen+inline+patches
  emacs-app @24.2_1+fullscreen+inline+patches (active)
$ sudo port activate emacs-app @23.4_1
--->  Computing dependencies for emacs-app
--->  Deactivating emacs-app @24.1_0
--->  Cleaning emacs-app
--->  Activating emacs-app @23.4_1
--->  Cleaning emacs-app
$ sudo port activate emacs-app @24.1_0
--->  Computing dependencies for emacs-app
--->  Deactivating emacs-app @23.3_4
--->  Cleaning emacs-app
--->  Activating emacs-app @24.1_0
--->  Cleaning emacs-app
```

Is editing an Mediawiki instance with Emacs that obscure a practice?  It seems if one uses Emacs and edits any Mediawiki pages sufficiently frequently, bringing the two in one place would be an intuitional need.

Comment: Quite obscure, yes. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:External_editors was even removed. (Please post your experience on the talk page for reference and to the developers' instruction!)